# Getting an error while trying the context API in React JS. I am using context API with classes in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-context

I am trying the context API of React in my code. I tried the following code and getting the error

> **ReferenceError: Cannot access 'MyContextApi' before initialization**

**Context.api.parent.js**:

```
import ContextChildOne from "./Context.api.childone";
import ContextChildTwo from "./Context.api.childtwo";
export const MyContextApi = React.createContext({});

class ContextParent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>context api parent tag</p>
        <MyContextApi.Provider value={{ concept: "Context API" }}>
          <ContextChildOne>
            <ContextChildTwo />
          </ContextChildOne>
        </MyContextApi.Provider>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ContextParent;
```

**I am consuming the above context API in the below file**

**Context.api.childtwo.js**:

```
import { MyContextApi } from "./Context.api.parent";

class ContextChildTwo extends React.Component {
  //   static contextType = MyContextApi;
  render() {
    // let concept = this.context;
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Child two of context</p>
        <p>
          THIS IS THE EXAMPLE OF CONTEXT API TO AVOID PROPS DRILLDOWN.
          THIS CONCEPT <span>{this.context.concept}</span>
        </p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ContextChildTwo.contextType = MyContextApi;
export default ContextChildTwo;
```

> I tried keeping `export const MyContextApi = React.createContext({});` in other file and import it but it is of no use, i am getting the same error.
>
> > Pls, help me to solve this error **ReferenceError: Cannot access 'MyContextApi' before initialization**

Answer (score 0):

I moved the code `export const MyContextApi = React.createContext({});` to another file and imported it both in the parent and child components. Then, my code worked correctly without error.

> Prior I tried importing only in the parent component and it didn't worked. Now, it is working.